# How much damage could hoof fingers do?

Tags: creature-design, hand-to-hand-combat

The scenario we have is a creature with a body like the chalicotherium but with a little straighter posture, so it has a bit of hunch. It has hands but at the end of its fingers where our fingernails start are hooves that resemble those of a deer. It uses these hooves to "finger walk" (like how apes knuckle-walk but instead of the knuckles it's the end of the fingers for support, evolution is not a factor) so wear down can be factor in and as it moves like an orangutan so we can put that muscle use into account. The creature is about 40 feet high with a estimated weight of 8,880 pounds (math has never been my strong suit so apologies in advance if the math is obviously off) If this creature slapped or hit say a concrete building about the same height as it or a tiger the same size as it. What amount of damage would those hooves do?

Comment: I think the first problem that comes to mind is being able to grip anything. The ridges that create a person's fingerprint are important for grasping and releasing objects, so I'd assume not having them would make it difficult to pick things up properly.

Comment: Please make this a WB question, the answer could be anything from "very painful" to "easy to dodge"

Comment: VTC:Needs Details, but I could have voted VTC:Needs More Focus. You're allowed to ask only one question (you're asking up to four questions, depending on interpretation). The [help/on-topic] requires questions to be specific and answerable. What specific problem are you having? Which specific hoof design do you want us to consider? Are you asking if such a hand could use tweezers? Whether or not they'd be a problem if balled into a fist? What would happen if used to slap someone? It would definitely be a problem if hanging from a ledge....

Comment: This is closer, tell us what you want to damage please. Are you attacking humans? Obviously you won’t do any damage to an armored tank, so we need to know what the opponents will be.  Then it can be opened up.

Comment: You should be able to test this out for yourself rather than asking losers like us on the internet.

Comment: How big is the creature and what is its body type/shape?  For example, "It's proportioned like an orangutan but it's 400 kg" or "it's a 50 kg kangaroo using its front paws".  IMO, once that detail gets added then the question is sufficiently defined that I would happily vote to re-open.

Comment: We need to know not only mass but speed.  Are this creature's joint ratios set up for speed or strength?

Comment: I think your height/weight seems a little off. Elephants weigh about 9000lb and are 10ft tall. Even with more sloth-like posture, maybe they would be 20ft tall. That weight at 40ft seems pretty slim. For example, sperm whales are about 50ft long and weigh 90,000lb

Answer (score 1):

This is a really difficult question to answer, because there are so many variables that would affect the outcome. For instance, the strength of the creature's muscles, the weight of the creature, the size of the hooves, the speed at which the creature is moving when it makes contact, the surface that it makes contact with, etc.

Without knowing all of those variables, it's impossible to say definitively how much damage the hooves would do. However, we can make some rough estimates based on what we do know.

Assuming that the creature weighs 8,880 pounds (4,000 kg) and is moving at a speed of 10 mph (4.5 m/s) when it makes contact, we can estimate that the hooves would have a kinetic energy of approximately 40 kilojoules.

Now, kinetic energy is not directly equivalent to damage, but it's a good way to compare the relative destructive potential of different impacts. For comparison, a 1 kg (2.2 lb) object falling from a height of 10 meters (33 ft) would have a kinetic energy of approximately 98 joules, and a car travelling at 30 mph (13.4 m/s) may have KE roughly at 161 kJ.

So based on these estimates, we can say that the hooves would have destructive potential somewhere between that of a small object falling from a moderate height, and a car travelling at highway speeds. Obviously, the actual amount of damage done would depend on a lot of other factors (like what the hooves hit, how hard they hit, etc.), but this should give you a general idea.